# How can i create for loop like C++ in python?

Tags: python-2.7

i am new in python, how can i create the following for loops in python?
totalnumber of records = 3
IN_QUERY_LIMIT = 500
`for (i = 0, i < totalnumberofrecords, i+=IN_QUERY_LIMIT)
    for (i = 0; i< IN_QUERY_LIMIT; ++i)`

can any body help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

```
for i in range(0, totalnumberofrecords, IN_QUERY_LIMIT):
```